# Como puedo separar un link UTM

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

como puedo separar un url de UTM
es decir tengo este link

http://localhost:50666/?utm_source=facebook_lp&utm_medium=adp&utm_campaign=inversionistas&utm_term=carrusel&utm_content=adp_verano&fbclid=IwAR3WTjD0QEz7VOcrujEr7Zro_8I0rhd56HiC1Zwz9WZqyHDLeN2kBeYQs5k#project-form

y quiero que quede asi ..

?utm_source=facebook_lp&utm_medium=adp&utm_campaign=inversionistas&utm_term=carrusel&utm_content=adp_verano&fbclid=IwAR3WTjD0QEz7VOcrujEr7Zro_8I0rhd56HiC1Zwz9WZqyHDLeN2kBeYQs5k#project-form

para poder concatenar ese utm con otro link.. Por favor ayúdenme

Answer (score 0):

Si es desde codigo servidor podrias usar la clase `Uri`

```
string url = "http://localhost:50666/?utm_source=facebook_lp...";
Uri uri = new Uri(url);

string host = uri.Authority;
```

aqui un ejemplo que valua todas las propiedades de la clase `Uri`

[Uri Class Properties](https://dotnetfiddle.net/125u7T)